# Ficar testando até uma variável ser criada no php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou enviando um ajax para uma tabela, porém essa tabela só pode ser criada depois de receber o valor, porém ela esta sendo criada antes em branco, como posso fazer uma verificação para a tabela ser gerada só depois de receber o valor ajax, ficar em um loop testando a variavel ser interromper o codigo php até a variavel receber o seu valor correto.

Tentei isso e não foi:

```
 if (isset($_POST['IdAparelho']))
            {
              $query = ("select id_principal from componentes where id_secundario = ".$_POST['IdAparelho']." ");
              $ids = mysqli_query($con,$query);
              while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($ids))
              {
                  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","roberto","","manutencao");
                  $query = ("select * from componentes where id_principal = ".$linha[0]." ");
                  $componentes = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                  $resultado = mysqli_fetch_row($componentes);

                  $id_componente = $resultado[1];
                  $codigo = $resultado[2];
                  $nome = $resultado[3];
                  $entrada = $resultado[4];
                  $saida = $resultado[5];
                  $f = $resultado[6];
                  $m = $resultado[7];
                  $g = $resultado[8];
                  $gg = $resultado[9];
                  $total = ($f + $m + $g + $gg);

                  $id_componente = $resultado[1];
                  $codigo = $resultado[2];
                  $nome = $resultado[3];
                  $entrada = $resultado[4];
                  $saida = $resultado[5];
                  $f = $resultado[6];
                  $m = $resultado[7];
                  $g = $resultado[8];
                  $gg = $resultado[9];
                  $total = ($f + $m + $g + $gg);

                  print "<tr>";
                    print "<td><strong>".$id_componente."</strong></td>";
                    print "<td><strong>".$codigo."</strong></td>";
                    print "<td><strong>".$nome."</strong></td>";
                    print "<td><strong>".$entrada."</strong></td>";
                    print "<td><strong>".$saida."</strong></td>";
                    print "<td><strong>".$f."</strong></td>";
                    print "<td><strong>".$m."</strong></td>";
                    print "<td><strong>".$g."</strong></td>";
                    print "<td><strong>".$gg."</strong></td>";
                    print "<td><strong>".$total."</strong></td>";
                  print "</tr>";
                }
            }
          ?>
```

CÓDIGO AJAX:

```
     $(function () {    
        $("#visualizarAparelhos").submit(function (e) {
        var index = $("#IdAparelho").attr('data-index');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST", 
          url: "administrador.php",
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {IdAparelho: index}
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }); 
    });
    });
```

Comment: Por favor, mostre o código da criação da tabela.

Comment: Editei a postagem

Comment: Isto está sendo enviado usando Ajax: `$_POST['IdAparelho']`? Se sim, você já checou se existe algum valor dentro dessa variável?

Comment: Chequei sim, o problema é que a variável só deixa de ser nula, depois que a tabela já foi criada.

Comment: Roberto, na sua função javascript coloque um `console.log(index)` para ver se está variável está com algum valor antes de enviar para o php.

Comment: Fiz o teste, está sim passando o valor 1.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49656/discussion-between-cesar-and-roberto-albino).

Answer (score 0):

1° - você abre uma conexão para cada linha da consulta `"select id_principal from componentes where id_secundario = ".$_POST['IdAparelho']."` te sugiro abrir 1 conexão só e fechar ela depois do loop

2° - esta situação não poderia ser resolvida com

```
if (isset($_POST['IdAparelho']))
        {
          $query = ("select * from componentes where id_secundario = ".$_POST['IdAparelho']." ");
          $ids = mysqli_query($con,$query);
          while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($ids))
          {

              $id_componente = $linha[1];
              $codigo        = $linha[2];
              $nome          = $linha[3];
              $entrada       = $linha[4];
              $saida         = $linha[5];
              $f             = $linha[6];
              $m             = $linha[7];
              $g             = $linha[8];
              $gg            = $linha[9];
              $total         = ($f + $m + $g + $gg);
```

3º - Onde você "testa a variavel que vai interromper o codigo php" ?

Comment: if (isset($_POST['IdAparelho']))  , <------ aqui, eu só posso criar a tabela depois que $_POST['IdAparelho'] ja ter o seu valor.

Comment: Você fica requisitando esta página até ter algum valor no "$_POST['IdAparelho']" ?

Comment: Estou tentando fazer isso, não consegui ainda.

Comment: Valida no Jquery se tem algo para ser enviado antes de enviar para o PHP, vai evitar de você fazer Ns requisições...

Comment: O problema é que depois que o servidor passa ali e encontra a variável vazia ele não volta mais, dai o código não é executado.

Comment: Coloca o código que faz a chamada ajax

Comment: Editei a publicação.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49669/discussion-between-bartolomeu-s-gusella-and-roberto-albino).